# Categorizing Pandas column with the indiviual custom bins (tresholds)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have a `dataframe` with some numeric values stored in column *"value"*, accompanied by their respective categorical tresholds (warning levels in this case), stored in other columns (in my case *"low"*, *"middle"*, *"high"*):

```
     value    low  middle    high
0   179.69  17.42   88.87  239.85
1     2.58  17.81   93.37  236.58
2     1.21   0.05    0.01    0.91
3     1.66   0.20    0.32    4.57
4     3.54   0.04    0.04    0.71
5     5.97   0.16    0.17    2.55
6     5.39   0.86    1.62    9.01
7     1.20   0.03    0.01    0.31
8     3.19   0.08    0.01    0.45
9     0.02   0.03    0.01    0.10
10    3.98   0.18    0.05    0.83
11  134.51  78.63  136.86  478.27
12  254.53  83.73  146.33  486.65
13   15.36  86.07   13.74  185.16
14   85.10  86.12   13.74  185.16
15   15.12   1.37    6.09   30.12
```

I would like to know in which category each value falls (e.g. first value would be *middle*, second would be *below_low*, since it's smaller than any of its tresholds, third would be *high*, ... you get the idea). So here is the expected output:

```
     value    low  middle    high   category
0   179.69  17.42   88.87  239.85     middle
1     2.58  17.81   93.37  236.58  below_low
2     1.21   0.05    0.01    0.91       high
3     1.66   0.20    0.32    4.57     middle
4     3.54   0.04    0.04    0.71       high
5     5.97   0.16    0.17    2.55       high
6     5.39   0.86    1.62    9.01     middle
7     1.20   0.03    0.01    0.31       high
8     3.19   0.08    0.01    0.45       high
9     0.02   0.03    0.01    0.10     middle
10    3.98   0.18    0.05    0.83       high
11  134.51  78.63  136.86  478.27        low
12  254.53  83.73  146.33  486.65     middle
13   15.36  86.07   13.74  185.16     middle
14   85.10  86.12   13.74  185.16     middle
15   15.12   1.37    6.09   30.12     middle
```

So far I use this ugly procedure of "manually" checking line by line, stopping at the first category (from higher to lower), being bigger that the current value:

```
df["category"]="below_low"    
for i in df.index:
    for cat in ["high","middle","low"]:
        if df.loc[i,"value"]>df.loc[i,cat]:
            df.loc[i,"category"]=cat
            break
```

I am aware of the `pd.cut()` method, but I only know how to use it with a predefined generic tresholds list. Can somebody tell what am I missing?

Comment: i recommend a set of nested calls to `numpy.where`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

- remove column `value`
- compare with [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) (less then)
- change order of columns
- cumulative sum columns - first `True` get `1`
- compare with `1` by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)

---

```
mask = df.drop('value',axis=1)
         .lt(df['value'], axis=0)
         .reindex(columns=['high','middle','low'])
         .cumsum(axis=1)
         .eq(1)
```

If all values in columns `high`, `middle` and `low` are `False` then some correctness is necessary. I create new column with inverting `mask` and `all`.

```
mask['below_low'] = (~mask).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
     high middle    low below_low
0    True  False  False     False
1   False  False  False      True
2    True  False  False     False
3   False   True  False     False
4    True  False  False     False
5    True  False  False     False
6   False   True  False     False
7    True  False  False     False
8    True  False  False     False
9   False   True   True     False
10   True  False  False     False
11  False  False   True     False
12  False   True  False     False
13  False   True   True     False
14  False   True   True     False
15  False   True  False     False
```

Last call [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['category'] = mask.idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
     value    low  middle    high   category
0   179.69  17.42   88.87  239.85       high
1     2.58  17.81   93.37  236.58  below_low
2     1.21   0.05    0.01    0.91       high
3     1.66   0.20    0.32    4.57     middle
4     3.54   0.04    0.04    0.71       high
5     5.97   0.16    0.17    2.55       high
6     5.39   0.86    1.62    9.01     middle
7     1.20   0.03    0.01    0.31       high
8     3.19   0.08    0.01    0.45       high
9     0.02   0.03    0.01    0.10     middle
10    3.98   0.18    0.05    0.83       high
11  134.51  78.63  136.86  478.27        low
12  254.53  83.73  146.33  486.65     middle
13   15.36  86.07   13.74  185.16     middle
14   85.10  86.12   13.74  185.16     middle
15   15.12   1.37    6.09   30.12     middle
```

Solution with multiple [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as pointed [Paul H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253069/categorizing-pandas-column-with-the-indiviual-custom-bins-tresholds#comment71664321_42253069):

```
df['category'] = np.where(df['high'] < df['value'], 'high', 
                 np.where(df['middle'] < df['value'], 'medium',
                 np.where(df['low'] < df['value'], 'low', 'below_low')))

print (df)
     value    low  middle    high   category
0   179.69  17.42   88.87  239.85       high
1     2.58  17.81   93.37  236.58  below_low
2     1.21   0.05    0.01    0.91       high
3     1.66   0.20    0.32    4.57     medium
4     3.54   0.04    0.04    0.71       high
5     5.97   0.16    0.17    2.55       high
6     5.39   0.86    1.62    9.01     medium
7     1.20   0.03    0.01    0.31       high
8     3.19   0.08    0.01    0.45       high
9     0.02   0.03    0.01    0.10     medium
10    3.98   0.18    0.05    0.83       high
11  134.51  78.63  136.86  478.27        low
12  254.53  83.73  146.33  486.65     medium
13   15.36  86.07   13.74  185.16     medium
14   85.10  86.12   13.74  185.16     medium
15   15.12   1.37    6.09   30.12     medium
```

Comment: You are a natural wonder, jezrael! :) Though, it looks like a quite advanced solution to a seemingly simple task. At least I am calmed that I haven't missed some embarrasingly straight forward use of pd.cut()... Thanks!

Comment: This is a golden showcase for vector operations! +1 Sir.

Answer (score 2):

In every other universe, you should use jezrael classic vector ways. However, if you're curious about `apply` way of doing things, then, you could

```
In [702]: df.apply(lambda x: 'high' if x.value > x['high'] 
                        else 'middle' if x.value > x['middle'] 
                        else 'low' if x.value > x['low'] 
                        else 'below low', axis=1)
Out[702]:
0        middle
1     below low
2          high
3        middle
4          high
5          high
6        middle
7          high
8          high
9        middle
10         high
11          low
12       middle
13       middle
14       middle
15       middle
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks John for being nice to beginners :) ! At the moment, it is so much easier for me to comprehend apply-like solutions. Those vector operations seem so unintuitive to me... :(